# How to insert NULL values to a DFS table in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

I have a DFS table with multiple columns. To insert data to DFS tables, only `append` and `tableInsert` are allowed. Now I want to insert data to the table while leaving some fields empty. How do I do it in GUI? And how do I do it through JAVA API?

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to the DolphinDB user manual:
https://www.dolphindb.com/help/DataTypesandStructures/DataTypes/DataTypeConversion.html

There's a conversion function for each data type. Use the conversion function to create a NULL value with the associated data type, like string(), timestamp(), and so on. The advantage of doing so is to determine the data type of the NULL value. In JAVA-API, use the operation void setNull(int Index) to set NULL values. This operation can be applied on all Vector classes.
For example, BasicStringVector.setNull(1) controls the second element of the vector. Then construct a BasicTable using BasicStringVector to be appended to distributed tables. For details, refer to https://github.com/dolphindb/api-java#72-save-data-to-a-distributed-table.
Also note that, no matter with GUI or JAVA-API, the order of the columns in the appended data must be consistent with the ditributed table.